# VerifyError - Verifier rejected class

Tags: android, verifyerror

I'm developing for 2.2 (`minSdkVersion=8`) and suddenly I'm getting this error:

```
arbitrarily rejecting large method (regs=75 count=28584)
rejected Lcom/Demo/Loyalty/SelectType;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
Verifier rejected class Lcom/Demo/Loyalty/SelectType;
Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/Demo/Loyalty/SelectType;)


java.lang.VerifyError: com.Demo.Loyalty.SelectType
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It was working fine until now.

Note : `SelectType` class has around 16000 lines of code but that is not that large I guess.

I search a lot on net and from answers, I did following:

- Clean the project
- Reset the ADB
- Restart emulator/device/eclipse
- Checked that third party library field is checked in build path

But I'm still getting that error.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The steps you've described probably won't help.

The thing is, it's not a Dalvik issue. Similar verifier is employed in the Oracle Java VM for example. Simple answer: *your method is too complex*. The error you see is mainly caused by too many:

- parameters
- local variables
- exception handlers
- code instructions

More precisely, the issue has been described in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/4qNoIdBHYFc

To quote:

> The value of (number of registers * number of instruction words) is
>   larger than 2^21. (...)
>   it's intended to
>   prevent the verifier from bloating up an app's native heap.

You can also see similar report here: http://www.mentby.com/Group/android-developers/verifyerror-arbitrarily-rejecting-large-method.html with pointers on how to resolve the issue:

> Yep, the Dalvik compiler attempts to assign a "register" to every 
>   local variable in the method.  It should be able to handle that many, 
>   but apparently can't.  By making them instance variables you remove 
>   the compiler's need/desire to "manage" them (and also make the method 
>   a fair amount smaller).

So to solve it, you should generally break the large method (probably `onClick()`?) into smaller pieces. Also, converting local variables to class fields seemed to help some people with the same issue.

Comment: but in my case, how do I know which method is causing `arbitrarily rejecting large method (regs=75 count=28584)` to occur?

Comment: the largest one :D but seriously, it's in the warning: `com.Demo.Loyalty.SelectType.onClick()`

Comment: its overridden method for click events. I have click event handlers for all the buttons in my activity(viewflipper) in this method. It's around 3200 lines long.

Comment: please read my answer carefully - it doesn't matter what the method does. also its length isn't the only factor involved - number of variables is of the same importance here. just break your method to a few smaller methods and you'll be fine.

Comment: Okay. But what if method method1(), say 100 lines long, is calling another method method2() which is 50 lines long. So what will be the effective lenghth of method1() ???

Comment: ah, this is your concern. the effective length will be 100 lines. so it's fairly easy - simply paste chunks of code to helper methods. the key is to lower method length and/or number of variables just in that one `onClick()` method. you don't have to worry about others.

Comment: Okay. Thats it. I got it. Thanks a ton buddy.

Comment: ...until you hit Android's method limit

Comment: For what its' worth, using jack and java 1.8 w/ the N preview lead to this problem for me.  So if you have it turned on, try turning jack off and going back to 1.7.  This is with preview 1 of android studio 2.2